# Broken insertion sort

Tags: java, algorithm, insertion-sort

I've been debugging this piece of code for a while now and I simply can't figure out why it doesn't work. It's an attempt at implementing a sequential insertion sort in Java.

```
public void resultSort(int[] resultSet){
    int j;
    for(int i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++){
        j = i;
        while(j > 0 && resultSet[j-1] < resultSet[j]){
            swap(j, j-1);
            j = j-1;
        }
    }
}

public void swap(int index1, int index2){
    int sw = numbers[index1];
    numbers[index1] = numbers[index2];
    numbers[index2] = sw;
}
```

If somebody could point out the error here, I'd be very happy. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who's `numbers` and who's `resultSet`?

Comment: @webuster numbers is an n-length int array declared in class scope. resultSet is a shorter int array (argument to the resultSort method).

Comment: Your code works correctly for me. Are you passing `numbers[]` into your function?

Comment: Sequential identical numbers at the end of resultSet will instantly abort the inner loop.  Is that the behaviour you're not expecting?  So an array like `5 1 1` will never sort properly.  But it looks (without testing) like everything else is ok. (Edit.. actually that should work, since the previous iteration should result in `1 5 1`, which will sort correctly)

Comment: When you say "broken" and "it doesn't work", what happens? Error msg? incorrect result?

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold well you should probably maintain some consistency and pass the `resultSet` to your `swap` function so that your swapping actually takes place in that same array.

Comment: @webuster you should turn the last comment into an answer.

Comment: BTW, it seams, it works for inputs `int[] array = {1, 3, 4, 7, 4, 5, 3, 2, 9, 1};` it returns `[0] = 9
[1] = 7
[2] = 5
[3] = 4
[4] = 4
[5] = 3
[6] = 3
[7] = 2
[8] = 1
[9] = 1` provide input for which it failed.

Comment: @webuster that's where the problem is!! Thank you so much! Post it in an answer, and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: @HenrikHillestadLøvold just added an answer, only now I saw your above comment. Try to be a little more specific in your future questions, it's often not easy as an outsider to actually see your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have an issue with `numbers` vs `resultSet`. If you pass your `numbers` array as a parameter to your sorting function, it *can* work.

Some advice:

- pass on your `resultSet` as parameter to your `swap` function so as to maintain consistency on which array you're actually sorting
- refrain from using class-scoped arrays for that kind of operations (this one is arguable and depends on your actual task)

Answer (score 1):

If you call `resultSort(numbers)` it works. Your algorithm sorts descending. Here is my testcode I did some small changes to make it all static. I guess the problem is, that **resultSort** is not called with parameter **numbers**.

```
    static int numbers[] = new int[]{34, 24, 56, 12, 45, 2, 53, 758};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        resultSort(numbers);
        for (int i : numbers) {
            System.out.println(i + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void resultSort(int[] resultSet) {
        int j;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSet.length; i++) {
            j = i;
            while (j > 0 && resultSet[j - 1] < resultSet[j]) {
                swap(j, j - 1);
                j = j - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void swap(int index1, int index2) {
        int sw = numbers[index1];
        numbers[index1] = numbers[index2];
        numbers[index2] = sw;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I also reproduced the code like this, and it works!!! so author should provide an array, in which case it doesn't work.